# Is there a version of version of time.time() that returns an int type?

Tags: python, time, int, epoch, timeit

My code needs to work with integer UNIX time, but `time.time()` is inadequate for my use case. It returns a float, and casting it to int or flooring it using math.floor() takes too long when recorded using timeit.timeit.

The output of `timeit.timeit(lambda : time())` is about .12 seconds, good enough for my use case, but not an int.
The output of `timeit.timeit(lambda : int(time()))` is about .25 seconds, too long for my use case.
`timeit.timeit(lambda : math.floor(time()))` is about .36 seconds, the worst of the three.

Timing is very important, so I would prefer some built in function that returns the UNIX time as an int rather than a float.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
def main():
    # The value of proceed goes up to 120.
    proceed = 1
    # timeout is some timestamp set at runtime, 2 days from the start of execution.
    while int(time()) <= timeout:
        # tps() uses int(time()), and this is what I want fixed.
        if proceed == tps():
            batchSend(tps())
            proceed += 1
        # These functions also use int(time())
        tocollect = mine()
        collect(tocollect)
```

Comment: You are aware that `timeit` runs the measured code several times? Where "several" might be something like a million.

Comment: I didn't know that. Reading the docs, I didn't pick out that timeit has a default value. If I were to divide .25 seconds by 1000000, I guess that would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I didn't do my homework. timeit.timeit() has a default `number` value that is set at 1 million, so the real value is much smaller than I thought.